# advanced numpy boolean indexing

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have multiple copies of boolean indexing, and I'm wondering if there is any vectorized way to do the index.

The condition boolean array has shape `(3, 2)` and both true value and false value have the shape `(2, 4)`

the desired output shape is `(3, 2, 4)`

A concrete example:

```
condition = np.array([[ True, False],
                      [ False, True],
                      [ True, False]])
true_value = np.array([[-0.32313401, -1.18761309,  0.4641033 , -0.05341635],
                       [-0.34072785,  0.45333183,  0.06974008, -1.4338561 ]])

false_value = np.array([[-0.0962484 ,  0.5257979 ,  1.22036481,  1.41949077],
                        [ 1.11138278,  0.56253736,  1.57296682, -0.12774857]])
```

the expected output:

```
np.array([[[-0.32313401, -1.18761309,  0.4641033 , -0.05341635],
           [ 1.11138278,  0.56253736,  1.57296682, -0.12774857]],
          [[-0.0962484 ,  0.5257979 ,  1.22036481,  1.41949077],
           [-0.34072785,  0.45333183,  0.06974008, -1.4338561 ]],
          [[-0.32313401, -1.18761309,  0.4641033 , -0.05341635],
           [ 1.11138278,  0.56253736,  1.57296682, -0.12774857]],
         ])
```

was expected to have some `where` where `expected = np.where(condition, true_value, false_value)` but it didn't work, right now only value was broadcast to conditions but not the otherway around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. In order for `np.where` to return a 3×2×4 array you need to add a dimension to `condition`:

```py
expected = np.where(condition[:, :, None], true_value, false_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution via the broadcast product:

```
expected = condtion[:,:,np.newaxis]*true_value \
          + (~condtion[:,:,np.newaxis])*false_value
```